# iOS equivalent of these transformations

Tags: android, ios, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to port some transformations from Android to iOS.
Specifically, I am trying to do the following (in Android):

```
matrix.reset();
matrix.postTranslate(xOffset,yOffset);
matrix.postScale(scaleX, scaleY);
```

Essentially I am trying to translate and scale. What is the equivalent of this code in iOS? I have already tried the following:

```
CATransform3D scaleTransform = CATransform3DMakeScale(scaleX, scaleY,1);
CATransform3D translateTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(xOffset,yOffset,0);
CATransform3D combined = CATransform3DConcat(scaleTransform, translateTransform)
```

The above two are not equivalent. Any pointers to debug this would really help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Android snippet, your matrix operation is Translate * Scale, but your iOS snippet uses Scale * Translate.

Matrix mulitplication is not Commutative, so the order is important.Try reversing the multiplication order i.e. instead of :

```
CATransform3D combined = CATransform3DConcat(scaleTransform, translateTransform)
```

use:

```
CATransform3D combined = CATransform3DConcat(translateTransform, scaleTransform)
```

Comment: Is applying the same transform on a layer idempotent?